# Trying to use awk to make ls show non-directories

Tags: awk, wildcards

I'm trying to show the list of all files which are not directories.
I type `ls -la | awk '$1 != "d*"'`hoping that it won't show any strings in the first column that start with `d` but it doesn't work the way I've expected. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!=` is just a string comparison (or number comparison depending on what is being compared) operator. For string comparison (`A != B`), depending on the `awk` implementation, it's either a byte to byte comparison, or for some (as required by POSIX), it's short for `A < B || A > B`, that is `A != B` tests whether `A` and `B` sort differently.

In any case, it is not a pattern matching operator. For that you have the `~` operator (negated with `!~`), though that's for regular expression matching, not wildcard pattern matching. You'd need:

```
ls -la | awk '$1 !~ /^d/'
```

Though here, you might as well use:

```
ls -la | grep -v '^d'
```

With `$1 != "d*"`, that would return *true* for anything except a first field that is (or sorts the same as with some `awk` implementaions) `d*`. `d*` as a regexp matches any number (including 0) of `d`, so `$1 !~ "d*"` would always return `false` as any string would contain at the very least 0 `d`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Why do we need both "/" around the "^d" when we're using the awk command?

Comment: @PanthersFan92, you can also use `$1 !~ "^d"`. The `/.../` form is more adapted when the regexp contains backslashes as with `"..."` they need to be escaped in some cases.

Comment: So in general how do I use wildcards with awk? Say I want to look for every string that ends with a specific letter for example? I can't just use `*`, right?

Comment: @PanthersFan92, `awk` doesn't do wildcards, it only does regular expressions. wildcards is generally for file name matching (as with `find` or shell globs) or for shell patterns as with the `case` construct or the `[[ foo = pattern ]]` operator of some shells.

Comment: @PanthersFan92, the regexp to match on `a` or `b` at the end would be `[ab]$`. Check http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for resources on regular expressions. regexps are at the core of many text processing utilities on Unix, it's worth spending some time learning them or at least the most common ones like the POSIX basic ones used by `grep` or `sed` or the extended one used by `grep -E` or `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to use `!~` instead of `!=` to match regex. `awk '$1 !~ /^d/`
- You don't want to parse the output of `ls` as it's inherently fragile.
- If you're just looking for non-directories, `find` has a `-type` option that you can use (you want to look into `-type f`.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with grepping the output of `ls` for display (the post said "to show"). `ls` is much quicker to type (even with a `grep`) than the full set of options needed for `find` to get the same information.

Comment: ITYM `$1 !~ /d.*/` but even then, that would be equivalent to `$1 !~ /d/`, that is match if `d` is found anywhere in `$1`. For the regexp equivalent of the shell wildcard `d*`, that would be `^d`.

Comment: @ilkkachu, grepping the output of `ls` like that doesn't work if there are file names that contain newline characters. You can use `ls -q` to work around that (but then that alters the display of file names and link targets), or use `ls -ld -- *(D^/)` in `zsh` to have `zsh` filter-out the directories, and `ls` do its job of displaying the files attributes and sorting the list (again as `zsh` does it as well).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh, right, I missed that GNU ls and the ls on OS X set `-q` only when outputting to a terminal. Though in any case, with "nice" filenames `ls | grep` is as ok as `ls` by itself, and with not-nice filenames both `ls` and `ls | grep` will give broken or ambiguous output, so they are equally bad. (And if `-q` isn't active when writing to a terminal, the output for non-nice filenames is both ambiguous _and_ ugly, with it, it's just ambiguous.)

Comment: In the end, any use of `ls` will be "wrong" in the strict sense, and all file listings should be NUL-separated or completely escaped. Too bad terminals will likely hide the NULs, and users likely will dislike the constant escaping and quoting. Luckily, an educated user might be aware of the caveats, or at least notice something funny going on, which makes looking at `ls` outputs ok in my mind. Automatically scripting based on it aggravates the issue enough that I'll accept that it shouldn't be done, however.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback both of you, I corrected the regex in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
  $ls -la | awk '$1 !~ /[d].*/ '
                 or
  $ls -l | grep -v ^d
```